# PHP mail script goes to junk mail when using an auto generated URL

Tags: php, email

Here is the PHP code I am using to send my email. For some reason this will go to junk mail if I include the following line: `$message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/violation.php?email=' . urlencode($fm_email) . "&key=$activation";` but if I remove this it will come to my inbox.

Can anyone help me solve this issue to allow this url in my email?

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: My Name <noreply@myname.com>' . "\r\n";
$subject  = 'Subject is here';
$message  = "Here is the message";
$message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/violation.php?email=' . urlencode($fm_email) . "&key=$activation";

mail($fm_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with how you send the email but 3rd party spam filtering services will 'tag' the email with spam probability values based on its **content** which will in turn have an effect on how _your email client_ classifies each message.

Comment: links in emails raise the spam rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use mail() function of php it will send your mail to junk only. Instead use SMTP php mailer function.

**Why we should use SMTP instead PHP mail():**

**SMTP** log in to an actual account on a mailserver and send the mail through SMTP to another mail server. If the mail server is configured correctly, your mails are sent from an actual account on a mailserver and will not wind up flagged as spam.

**Mail** sent with the mail() function is sent with sendmail in most cases. There is no authentication going on and it will almost always be flagged as spam if you use the "From:" in the extra headers.

This is because if you take a look at an original email file in say, gmail, you will see the headers that are sent. You are actually sending from user@serverhostname.tld and not someone@example.com like you had told the mail function to do.
If you use SMTP and view the original the email is actually sent from someone@example.com

You can download SMTP class from:

1. https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.smtp.php?r=170
2. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/14-PHP-Sends-e-mail-messages-via-SMTP-protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the following headers should prevent your email from getting in the junk/spam folder.

```
$headers     = 'From: ' . $website_name . ' <' . $own_emailaddress . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $name_sender . ' <' . $email_sender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Return-Path: Mail-Error <' . $error_emailaddress . '>' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers    .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
```

Don't forget to define the variables in the code.